`firebase deploy` error "Project has no namespace"
I tried running firebase deploy --only functions to upload a new Node.js cloud functions to firebases, and I am presented with this error:
⚠  functions: failed to update function projects/my-app/locations/us-central1/functions/fixGeoLocErr
Failed to update function projects/busfluence-app/locations/us-central1/functions/fixGeoLocErr
⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, Validation failed for trigger projects/my-app/locations/us-central1/triggers/sendnewoffernotification-890412: The request was invalid: generic::not_found: Project has no namespace.: invalid argument
⚠  functions:  failed to create function projects/busfluence-app/locations/us-central1/functions/sendNewOfferNotification
Failed to create function projects/busfluence-app/locations/us-central1/functions/sendNewOfferNotification

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        sendNewOfferNotification(us-central1)
        fixGeoLocErr(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function fixGeoLocErr in region us-central1
- Error Failed to create function sendNewOfferNotification in region us-central1

One of the already existing functions called fixGeoLocErr failed to update, and the new function I made called sendNewOfferNotification failed to upload.
The only reason why I can imagine this being an issue is that I recently added a new iOS app to firebase and have switched my project to use the new one. I didn't make any changes to any cloud function configurations after doing this. Could that be the problem?
I actually ended up completely reinstalling all the Firebase CLI tools, and also reinstalled node/npm on my machine to no avail. Any ideas?

If the Firebase CLI is giving you error messages that are not clearly actionable, you should contact Firebase support directly to get help.

This was the function that I was trying to deploy:
const {onValueCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");

exports.sendNewNotification = onValueCreated("/transactions", (event) => {
    logger.log(`A new document was created`);
});

However, the onValueCreated function is made for the Real Time Database. In my project, I've been using Cloud Firestore, and RTDB isn't setup, hence the Project has no namespace error.
Instead, I did this:
const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");

exports.sendNewNotification = onDocumentWritten("/transactions", (event) => {
    logger.log(`A new document was created`);
});

This uses the triggers for Cloud Firestore instead of RTDB.
